# Coldfusion 2016 - 403 forbidden error for schedule tasks

Tags: iis, coldfusion, permissions

I have two schedule task which is running in coldfusion administrator. They are giving 403 forbidden error when run through coldfusion administrator. Here is the log which i get.

```
"Information","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8","02/22/17","10:11:00","","Task default.example - Get detail Dev triggered."
"Information","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4","02/22/17","10:11:00","","Task default.example - Get detail Live triggered."
"Error","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8","02/22/17","10:11:00","","403 Forbidden "
"Error","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4","02/22/17","10:11:00","","403 Forbidden "
```

The task url is running good through browser. It seems that it is something related to permission problem. I have checked the permission of coldfusion Application 'log on as' user on the CFIDE directory and task url directory. It has full control.

Can anyone guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This post is a little old but I've happened across the same problem and I thought I'd share our solution here.

We're running ColdFusion 2016 on a dedicated Windows 2012R2 box.  We have several client sites on our box and we're completely locked down using Peter Freitag's lockdown guide.

This is was a new server migration from a CF10 server on another box.  Once I set up the scheduled task exactly as we had done before, I received several "403 Forbidden" responses.

The only real way to troubleshoot this is to activate the "Save output to a file" option on the scheduled task itself and save the file to a directory where your CFUser has write access to. "CFUser" of course is the Windows user your CF service uses.

My first test of the URL was through Chrome on the server and it worked just fine so my URL was valid and of public access.

When I fired the scheduled task, it said "The scheduled task ran successfully" however the results of the output file showed it didn't.  In our case, an outside service called "Cloudflare" was blocking our request.  The error from Cloudflare asked us to enable cookies which we can't do in a scheduled task request.  In our case, our hosting provider must provide an exception for requests made from our server's dedicated IP.

Most of the time, these error are generated because of file permission issues on Windows.  If you're sure that your CFUser has read & execute permission to the requested template, then you need to output the scheduled task result to fully understand the error.

Comment: Thanks @DaveB... Surely this would be helpful for anyone which would face the same issue. thanks man.

Comment: Thanks @DaveB...I happened to face this exact issue and I was not sure whether my client's server had anything to do with Cloudflare. I did not get any output in a separate file from the scheduled task but I saw the 403 forbidden error in scheduler.log. I called the same link from CFHTTP and dumped the result and that is where there was a mention of "cloudflare-nginx". I spoke with the hosting team and this issue seems to have been resolved :)